# Passing variable from AJAX to PHP web API

Tags: php, ajax

I have a simple web api in php that calls one function called getData that is in the index.php file as follows:

index.php

```
<?
session_start();
require("lib.php");
require("api.php");

header("Content-Type: application/json");

    getData($name);

exit();
?>
```

the getData function is in the api.php file like this:

api.php

```
<?
function getData($name) {
$result = query("select * FROM table where name = $name");
    print json_encode($result);
}

?>
```

I want to retrieve the json using AJAX in my javascript as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var url = 'webAPI/index.php';
    var j = [];
    $.ajax({
           type: 'GET',
           url: url,
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(data) { j = data;},
           async: false
           });
```

This works perfect if no $name variable is being passed, but I need to pass the $name variable from the AJAX to the index.php file to get my proper sql result. I have tried making the AJAX a post but to no avail.

Comment: what is `query()`? have you checked the return value in `getData` to see if there is anything to return?

Answer (score 1):

The variables sent by a *GET* AJAX request are available from the superglobal `$_GET`. For example, if this is your jQuery code:

```
 $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: url,
       dataType: 'json',
       data: { name:"something" }, // you can replace name with whatever you need
       success: function(data) { j = data;},
       async: false
 });
```

Then you can access the name variable with `$_GET["name"]`. Thus you can use the data sent from the client with `getData($_GET["name"]);`

Also, make sure you are using proper functions to access your database, such as [MySQLi for PHP](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Fbook.mysqli.php&ei=U-epVNb7KsOvyAS3sYGoAw&usg=AFQjCNEqr4MIMr-la3jWWjZ1PQbJFnyFHw&sig2=83A3ZIFCSVJUaWJVHbKPNw).